# OpenCV with uEye Cameras

Tags: c++, qt, opencv, ueye

I need to use OpenCV with uEye Ethernet Camera. The problem is that I wasn't finding some useful tips regarding some example codes.

The source code provided with the installation is really linked to MFC stuff which is not what I want. It's really complicated to get rid of that, it was causing me so much problems (CWnd, Afx, Dialogs...)

I would like to read some frames from the camera and record some snapshots.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found this document in the internet

http://master-ivi.univ-lille1.fr/fichiers/Cours/uEye_SDK_manual_enu.pdf

Comment: no sorry maybe tell here if you find more I have also a ids camera  but no time to research it.... :)

Comment: if you have labview the examples of it are not bad for learning purpose how to use the apis or you could try the python api http://code.google.com/p/pyueye/

Answer (score 4):

You can find the whole SDK description here: https://en.ids-imaging.com/manuals-ueye-software.html

Just simply make and account and you can access it. The documentation is really good.